# Any Open Source examples of using PLActorKit?

Tags: objective-c, open-source, actor

I've intrigued by Plausible Labs PLActorKit:

http://code.google.com/p/plactorkit/

But the documentation just has single single Echo example.  Before diving into it further I'm curious if there are any open source projects using PLActorKit I can take a look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search on [GitHub](http://github.com/) revealed [TumblKitNG](http://github.com/uasi/TumblKitNG), which seems to make use of PLActorKit.